# C#/ASP.Net - ImageButton OnClick CodeBehind function

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, void

I've got default.aspx/default.aspx.cs and other.cs where i "store" a bunch of functions.

In my default.aspx i've :

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CssClass="btn_img" ImageUrl="./images/1.png" runat="server" OnClick='<%# "setFunction(" +Eval("aGUID") +")" %>' />
```

in my default.aspx.cs

```
protected void setFunction(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string istr = e.ToString();
    var iguid = new Guid(istr);
    // this are classes/functions stored in other.cs
    ManageFun mfun = new ManageFun();
    mfun.setMM(iguid);
}
```

I though i was doing all right, but can't figure out what i'm doing wrong!
In matter of fact it does nothing!

Apreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it just be ***OnClick="setFunction"*** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
  <h3>ImageButton Sample</h3>

  Click anywhere on the image.<br /><br />

  <asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="ImageButton 1"
       ImageAlign="left"
       ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
       OnClick="ImageButton_Click"/>

  <br /><br />

  <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server"/>
```

and C# code

```
public void ImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
      {
         Label1.Text = "You clicked the ImageButton control at the coordinates: (" + 
                       e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString() + ")";
      }
```

No need to write these `<%#`

Here is the reference [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclick.aspx)

Comment: my setFunction is wating for a parameter of GUID type, shouldn't i pass it with Eval ? How is my function get to know the parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `asp:ImageButton` with `Onclick` which will not call the server side code with `Eval`.

Edit:

You can directly call like this :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CssClass="btn_img" ImageUrl="./images/1.png" runat="server" OnClick="setFunction"  />
```

if you want to pass the parameter to that function you can assign the param to the `CommandArguement` as below

```
CommandArguement='<%# Eval("aGUID") %>'
```

in your `SetFunction` you can retrieve like this

```
string val = e.CommandArguement.ToString()
```

Comment: @esko  fixed typo .. and i read my answer it giving some different meaning which i fixed

Comment: my setFunction is wating for a parameter of GUID type, shouldn't i pass it with Eval ? 
How is my function get to know the parameter ?